# set user rainlab last login timestamp by JWTAuth

Tags: laravel, octobercms, octobercms-plugins, jwt

I have managed to create jwtauth to connect my mobile app to octobercms backend
from this [reference](https://github.com/gpasztor87/oc-jwt-auth) 
but the last_login field is always empty, I believe this is not set by default.
this is authenticated function that I have

```
use Tymon\JWTAuth\JWTAuth;

public function __construct(JWTAuth $auth)
{
    $this->auth = $auth;
}

public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    try {
        if (! $token = $this->auth->attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))) {
            return response()->json([
                'errors' => [
                    'root' => 'Could not sign you in with those details.',
                ],
            ], 401);
        }
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        return response()->json([
            'errors' => [
                'root' => 'Failed.',
            ],
        ], $e->getStatusCode());
    }

    return response()->json([
        'data' => $request->user(),
        'meta' => [
            'token' => $token,
        ],
    ]);
}
```

it's called by this route.php from jwtauth folder

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () {
Route::post('auth/login','Autumn\JWTAuth\Http\Controllers\AuthController@authenticate');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Autumn\JWTAuth\Http\Controllers\AuthController@register');
Route::post('auth/logout', 'Autumn\JWTAuth\Http\Controllers\AuthController@logout');    

Route::group(['middleware' => 'jwt.auth'], function () {
    Route::get('auth/me', 'Autumn\JWTAuth\Http\Controllers\AuthController@user');        
});
```

how do we set user last_login timestamp?
I hope my question is clear to understand.

added plugin.php where i extended user plugin as requested by @HardikSatasiya since i got exception implementing his suggestion

```
use System\Classes\PluginBase;
use Rainlab\User\Controllers\Users as UsersController;
use Rainlab\User\Models\User as UserModels;
use Event;

class Plugin extends PluginBase
{
  public function registerComponents()
  {
  }

  public function registerSettings()
  {
  }

  public function boot()
  {
    UserModels::extend(function($model){

        $model->bindEvent('model.beforeSave',function() use ($model) {

            $users = \BackendAuth::getUser();               
            $model->backend_users_id = $users->id;              
            //above line result exception when calling method as @HardikSatasiya suggested          
            if(!empty($model->avatar)){
                $model->image_path = $model->avatar->getPath();
            }
            if(!empty($model->groups)){
                $model->membership = $model->groups[0]['name'];
            }
        });

        $model->addJsonable('users_detail','membership');
    }); 



    UsersController::extendFormFields(function($form,$model,$context){

        $form->addTabFields([
            'users_detail[0][gender]' => [
                'label' => 'Jenis Kelamin',
                'span' => 'left',
                'tab' => 'User Profile',
                'type' => 'radio',
                'options' => [
                    'Pria' => 'Pria',
                    'Wanita' => 'Wanita'
                ] 
            ],
            'users_detail[0][ttl]' => [
                'label' => 'Tempat/Tanggal Lahir',
                'type' => 'text',
                'span' => 'left',
                'tab' => 'User Profile'
            ],           
        ]);  
    });
  }
```

i add additional fields to user table by this separate plugin..

Comment: can you add more details how you call this, where did you put this code and little details about `$this->auth` object.

Comment: sorry for late respond.. i have updated my question with all the info you ask.. let me know if you need more data.. i really appreciate this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, may be because internal hooks are not called when this plugin externally logsin user.

> May be we need to **call it manually**, this code snippet can do it, just put given `code` after successful login.

```
// this will fire hooks and update `last_login`
// get authenticated user from the jwt authmanager
$user = $this->auth->authenticate($token);
$user->afterLogin();
```

> Added in your code below.

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    try {
        if (! $token = $this->auth->attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))) {
            return response()->json([
                'errors' => [
                    'root' => 'Could not sign you in with those details.',
                ],
            ], 401);
        }
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        return response()->json([
            'errors' => [
                'root' => 'Failed.',
            ],
        ], $e->getStatusCode());
    }

    // this will fire hooks and update `last_login`
    // get authenticated user from the jwt authmanager
    $user = $this->auth->authenticate($token);
    $user->afterLogin();
    // ^ this code

    return response()->json([
        'data' => $request->user(),
        'meta' => [
            'token' => $token,
        ],
    ]);
}
```

> this snippet will update `last_login` as expected. i did not test it but it will work as it should.

if any doubt or problem please comment.

Comment: i tried.. it result  Method[getUser] does not exist.. any idea??

Comment: Can you add result of `dd($this->auth);` need to check whoes object it is.

Comment: the result of `dd($this->auth);` is `JWTAuth{...}`

Comment: sir.. it result `Call to undefined method Autumn\JWTAuth\Classes\RainAuthAdapter::attempt()` pls advise..

Comment: ok can you do one thing `revert last changes i suggested` and then check this `dd($this->user());` if it returns user then we can use that.

Comment: `dd($this->user())` return an exception, i tried `dd($request->user())` return `user{...}` but when i called `afterLogin()` with it return an execption `Trying to get property of non-object` on plugin.php

Comment: where i extend user model and define `$users = \BackendAuth::getUser();` `$model->backend_users_id = $users->id;`

Comment: hmm your `use model is extended` ?

Comment: I guess I need to check it with installing that plugin, do you do anything extra so i can reproduce it.

Comment: i added `plugin.php` to my question to let you know how i extend user plugin from another plugin that i created..

Comment: hmm that are normal extension no issues there.

Comment: i added that plugin and checked. you can rever all changes what i suggested and use this one `$user = $this->auth->authenticate($token);  $user->afterLogin();` Also updated in answer please check it and let use know.

Comment: i tried.. still result the same exception.. on plugin.php `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: if i remove this `$model->backend_users_id = $users->id;` it works so very well.. did i make a mistake with this line..

Comment: finally... i didnt use `afterLogin()` instead i do this `$user->last_login = $user->freshTimestamp();`  it works with no exception.. thank you @HardikSatasiya for your guidance..

Comment: ok great if it helped you, then just mark answer or do have any other things left :)

Comment: Ok.. marked.. you should edit your answer.. thx @HardikSatasiya